# Suppose that $p: X \to B$ is a covering space where $X$ its not necessarily arc-connected. Prove that $p|_{X_0} :X_0 \to B$ is a covering space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $B$ be path connected and locally path connected. Suppose that $p \colon X \to B$ is a covering space where $X$ is not necessarily path connected. Let $X_0$ be a path component of $X$. Prove that $p|_{X_0} \colon X_0 \to B$ is a covering space.

For this I have to show 3 things. That:

1. $p|_{X_0} : X_0 \to B$ is a surjective and continuous function (which can be straight forward since $p$ is a covering space).
2. There exist an open set $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)= \sqcup V_{\alpha} $ with $V_{\alpha} \subset X_0$.
3. $p|_{V_{\alpha}} \colon V_{\alpha} \to U$ is a homeomorphism.

Since $p$ is a covering space there already exist a $W$ open set that satisfies 2 and 3 ($W$ is evenly covered).

Can someone help me to structure well the proof.

Comment: By arc-connected, do you mean path-connected?

Comment: There is a slight subtlety with #2: $p^{-1}(U)$ will be a union of subsets of $X$, not necessarily contained in $X_0$. You want to consider $p|_{X_0}^{-1}(U)$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $p \mid_{X_0}:X_0 \to B$ is certainly continuous, but needn't be surjective. Luckily some definitions (for instance, Hatcher's) do not require this.
2. I think you mean that **for every** $b \in B$, there is some open set $U \ni b$ such that $p\mid_{X_0}^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of sets in $X$ each of which is mapped homeomorphically to $U$ by $p\mid_{X_0}$ (I'm combining your 2 and 3).

We already know that such a $U$ exists because $p$ is a covering. By local path connectedness, we can assume that $U$ is path connected (otherwise replace it with a path connected set contained in $U$). Because $p$ is a cover, $p\mid_{X_0}^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint of sets (as above) *intersected with* $X_0$.

Because each copy of $U$ in $p^{-1}(U)$ is path connected, and $X_0$ is path connected, the disjoint sets of $p^{-1}(U)$ that intersect $X_0$ must lie entirely in $X_0$ (fill in details). Then, when we look at the restriction, $p\mid_{X_0}^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of sets in $X$ each of which is mapped homeomorphically to $U$ by $p$, and therefore by $p\mid_{X_0}$, as required.

Comment: $p \mid_{X_0}$ is surjective. Let $b \in B$. Take $\xi \in X_0$ and let $u$ be a path from $p(\xi)$ to $b$. It lifts to a path $\tilde u$ in $X$ starting at $\xi$ and ending at some $y \in X$. Clearly $y \in X_0$ and $p(y) = b$.